# C++ multiple multicast receiver with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio, multicast

I have to implement a multicast receiver able to join a list of multicast groups and process received data in a specific thread using boost. I did try the following code.....

```
boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket m_multicast_socket(m_io_service);

// listen address
boost::asio::ip::address listen_address  
     = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("0.0.0.0");

// listen port
unsigned short multicast_port = m_configuration->m_multicast_interface_port;

boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint( listen_address, multicast_port );

// open socket
m_multicast_socket.open( listen_endpoint.protocol() );

// set socket buffer size
m_multicast_socket.set_option( 
       boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::receive_buffer_size
               ( m_configuration->m_receiving_socket_buffer_size ) );

// other sockets could bind to listen_address
m_multicast_socket.set_option( boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true) );

boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable num_of_bytes_readable(true);

m_multicast_socket.io_control(num_of_bytes_readable);

m_multicast_socket.bind(listen_endpoint);


// joining a list of multicast group
for ( size_t i=0; i < multicast_groups.size(); ++i )
{
    boost::asio::ip::address multicast_address 
         = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string( multicast_groups[i] );

    m_multicast_socket.set_option( 
        boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(
            multicast_address ) );

    std::cout << multicast_groups[i] << " multicast group joined!" << std::endl;
}
```

And then to read data an infinite loop.......

```
while ( !m_exit )
{
    while ( !num_of_bytes_readable.get() )
    {
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1 ) );
    }

    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;

    size_t bytes_received = m_multicast_socket.receive_from(
        boost::asio::buffer( m_reading_buffer.get(), m_configuration->m_reading_buffer_size )
            , sender_endpoint );

    if ( bytes_received > 0 )
    {
       // process
    }

    boost::this_thread::yield();
}
```

But no data is received and the loop.....

```
while ( !num_of_bytes_readable.get() )
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 1 ) );
}
```

never exits.

I also did try the code of the multicast receiver example from the boost asio documentation
but the `async_recv_from` never returns.

Comment: You'll need one socket per multicast group.

Comment: I tryed to join a single multicast group but I did not receive any data. The point is that the join seems to fail.

Comment: We do use boost::asio for multicasting data. I haven't read your code, but maybe this helps: https://github.com/Eyescale/Collage/blob/master/co/rspConnection.cpp#L192

Answer (score 10):

There are a few changes that need to occur:

- As suggested in the comments, use a socket per multicast group.
- If the sender and receiver are on the same machine, then verify that the [`ip::multicast::enable_loopback`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__multicast__enable_loopback.html) option is true.
- The [`socket_base::bytes_readable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/bytes_readable.html) is an IO control command.  [`socket.io_control`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/io_control/overload1.html) executes a command on the socket, and `bytes_readable.get()` returns the value of the command.  Thus, the command needs to be executed each time to query how many bytes are available for reading.  An alternative, and arguable slightly more readable solution, is to use the [`socket.available()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/available/overload1.html) function.

---

Here is a simple example that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0854af10a6efef57) the usage of `socket_base::bytes_readable`.

```cpp
// Standard includes.
#include <iostream>

// 3rd party includes.
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void read(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket& socket)
{
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint sender;
  std::vector<char> buffer;
  std::size_t bytes_readable = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    // Poll until data is available.
    while (!bytes_readable)
    {
      // Issue command to socket to get number of bytes readable.
      boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable num_of_bytes_readable(true);
      socket.io_control(num_of_bytes_readable);

      // Get the value from the command.
      bytes_readable = num_of_bytes_readable.get();

      // If there is no data available, then sleep.
      if (!bytes_readable)
      {
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
      }
    }

    // Resize the buffer to store all available data.
    buffer.resize(bytes_readable);

    // Read available data.
    socket.receive_from(
      boost::asio::buffer(buffer, bytes_readable),
      sender);

    // Extract data from the buffer.
    std::string message(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());

    // Output data.
    std::cout << "Received message: ";
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
  }
}

void write(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket& socket,
           boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint& destination)
{
  std::string message;
  for (unsigned int i=0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << i;
    message = stream.str();
    socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message), destination);
    std::cout << "Sent message: " << message << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // Extract command-line arguments.
  bool receiver = std::string(argv[1]) == "receive";
  boost::asio::ip::address address =
    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[2]);
  unsigned short port = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned short>(argv[3]);

  // Create socket.
  using boost::asio::ip::udp;
  boost::asio::io_service service;
  udp::socket socket(service);
  socket.open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

  // Allow other processes to reuse the address, permitting other processes on
  // the same machine to use the multicast address.
  socket.set_option(udp::socket::reuse_address(true));

  // Guarantee the loopback is enabled so that multiple processes on the same
  // machine can receive data that originates from the same socket.
  socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true));
  socket.bind(
    udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(),
    receiver ? port /* same as multicast port */
             : 0 /* any */));
  udp::endpoint destination(address, port);

  // Join group.
  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  socket.set_option(ip::multicast::join_group(address));

  // Start read or write loops based on command line options.
  if (receiver) read(socket);
  else          write(socket, destination);
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./a.out receive 235.55.55.55 55555 &
$ sleep 1
$ ./a.out send 235.55.55.55 55555
Sent message: 0
Sent message: 1
Sent message: 2
Received message: 0
Received message: 1
Received message: 2
```

Comment: it is 2018 and I have Boost 1.66 installed.  I run your code on VC++ 2017 and it throws an error.  Any idea?