# How to make a simple multicast sender with boost c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have searched from the web and tried to implement it
Here is my code:
MulticastSender.h

```
// Standard includes.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

// 3rd party includes.
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class MulticastSender
{
public:
    typedef std::set<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint>::iterator distinationListIT;

    MulticastSender(const std::string& ip, const unsigned short& port);
    ~MulticastSender();

    void AddGroup(const std::string& ip);
    void LeaveGroup(const std::string& ip);
    void Send(const std::string& data);

private:
    std::set<boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint> m_destinationList;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket* m_socket;
    boost::asio::io_service m_service;
    unsigned short m_port;
};
```

MulticastSender.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MulticastSender.h"

MulticastSender::MulticastSender(const std::string& ip, const unsigned short& port)
{
    boost::asio::ip::address address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip);
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint destination(address, port);
    m_destinationList.insert(destination);

    // Create socket.
    m_socket = new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(m_service);
    m_socket->open(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4());

    // Allow other processes to reuse the address, permitting other processes on
    // the same machine to use the multicast address.
    m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));

    // Guarantee the loopback is enabled so that multiple processes on the same
    // machine can receive data that originates from the same socket.
    m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true));
    m_socket->bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), port));

    m_service.run();

    // Join group.
    m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(address));
}
MulticastSender::~MulticastSender()
{

}

void MulticastSender::AddGroup(const std::string& ip)
{
    boost::asio::ip::address address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip);
    // Join group.
    m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(address));
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint destination(address, m_port);
    m_destinationList.insert(destination);
}
void MulticastSender::LeaveGroup(const std::string& ip)
{
    boost::asio::ip::address address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip);
    // Leave group
    m_socket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::leave_group(address));
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint destination(address, m_port);
    m_destinationList.erase(destination);
}
void MulticastSender::Send(const std::string& data)
{
    for (distinationListIT it = m_destinationList.begin(); it != m_destinationList.end(); it++)
    {
        m_socket->send_to(boost::asio::buffer(data), *(it));
    }   
}
```

main.cpp

```
MulticastSender_3 sender("239.255.0.1", 6000);

while (true)
{
    sender.Send("Hello");
    std::cout << "Hello\n";
    Sleep(2000);
}
```

The problem is that I use a wireshark to capture the output, but I found that the destination ip 239.255.0.1 and port 5001 was used by the program and sending some meaningless message. Port 6000 didn't use.
I have try the example code from `\libs\asio\example\cpp03\multicast`, but the problem is that I cannot add group and leave group. Anyone knows how to make it works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12749727/1053968 provides a simple example.  Are you _absolutely_ certain that the traffic observed to `239.255.0.1:5001` correlates to each `send_to` operation?  Have you tried running a multicast receiver and seeing if the "Hello" message is received?

Comment: `Are you absolutely certain ...` > yes, I start Wireshark before my program start, and the wireshark cannot receiver anything. After my program started, wireshark started capturing things. Then I stop my program, wireshark becomes silence again.

Comment: Are multicast receivers not receiving the "Hello" message on `239.255.0.1:6000`?  I have not been able to duplicate the behavior described above.  It sees you may have correlation, but I would be surprised if it was causation.  Consider testing for reception of messages, trying a different address and port, as well as investigating why the add/leave group on the official examples fail.